# Android 500px in WebView

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, 500px

Is there any solution, how to sign-in into 500px with credentials that the user will type into webview of 500px.com sign-in page? I know, that there is the solution with using oAuth library for Android like this one https://github.com/wuman/android-oauth-client, but that is not the solution, I think.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some [documentation](https://github.com/500px/api-documentation) for 500px API. You can use it for your custom 500px app icluding authorization.

Comment: Well, many thanks. Really? I already know about this documentation, but that is just a abstraction of my question.